# How to detect mousing over NOTHING in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouse

I'm modifying this open source card game and adding a series of classes which are supposed to monitor changes within the game. One of these monitors can detect when you mouse over a card, I achieved this with the following code:

```
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        this.p = e.getPoint();
        this.pp = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this.SRC_STACK, e.getPoint(), GameArea.this);

        /*
         * this code detects when the mouse moves over a card.
         */
        this.OVER_STACK = (Stack) e.getSource();
        try {
            this.NEW_OVER_CARD = (Card)this.OVER_STACK.getComponentAt(this.p);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        if ( NEW_OVER_CARD != OVER_CARD ) {
            if ( NEW_OVER_CARD.isTurned() ) {
                manager.send(new HesitationEvent(0, NEW_OVER_CARD.getType() + NEW_OVER_CARD.getNumber() ) );
            }
        }

        this.OVER_CARD = NEW_OVER_CARD;
    }
```

This function is held in a mouse handler in one of my game classes. `Stack` is a class of the card game which represents a collection of card objects arranged in a stack. I modified the code to alert my monitor classes as you can see in the call of the method `manager.send()`.

**My problem is that I also want to detect when the users mouse leaves this card, or more specifically when a user is mousing over nothing.** I've tried detecting for (Stack) `null` in the `*OVER_CARD` variables, but they don't change when you leave a card, only when you mouse over another card.

**Is there a way to detect if there is nothing at the source of a mouse move/click event?**

Thanks in advance. Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Your try/catch statement is there because of the possibility that you are not over a stack, right?  Then you could just add code in your catch statement and not have to even worry about mouse entering/exiting events...

Comment: @user2253489: Just being curious: Can you provide a link to "this open source card game"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and use [`mouseExited()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseExited%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) and [`mouseEntered()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseEntered%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) to keep track.

Comment: Worked perfectly, much better than my original solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) interface.
There are two methods that could be useful for you:

- `void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)` - invoked when the mouse enters a component
- `void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)` - invoked when the mouse exits a component

There is some tutorial describing how to do this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    //code to be executed
}
```